# ToastMessageShow in Activity Create

Tags: basic4android

My loading layouts is around 5 seconds.  Instead of user seeing a blank screen, I decided to add this prior to loading layouts.

ToastMessageShow("Loading, Please Wait...", True)
DoEvents: DoEvents: DoEvents
Activity.LoadLayout("any")

I am not sure if this is solid enough to show the message.  1 Doevents does not show on the device or emulator.  2 does.

For those of you have long loading times, can you give me an idea what are you guys doing on the screen while the user is waiting.

I am thinking of abandoning the .bal and do everything with the codes.  Painful!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you measured 5 seconds on a real device? The emulator is very slow.
You can also separate your layout into several layout files and then only load the layout when it is needed.

Comment: Actually, Real Device is around 3 seconds and emulator is about 5 seconds.  I like your idea on separating the layouts.  Thanks again Erel.